# Comparing two columns and if it matches then it should be highlighted in another column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have two columns J and L.
If the value of J column matches with the corresponding value of L column, both the cells should be highlighted in red.

I am new to this Excel. I am not able to develop this macro.

Comment: It's not that bad, you are "not able to develop this macro", as you can achieve it without programming just by Excel's conditional formatting. Conditional formatting is a technique used by Microsoft Excel for formatting cells depending on cells evaluated value. If below answers are not enough, consider asking on SuperUser.com where you can get general help with Conditional Formatting in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with Conditional Formatting.Create a New Rule and add in

```
=$J1=$L1
```

Where by the two cells referenced are the first in the range that you want to compare.

[image]

Then in the Applies to box select all of your column `J` and `L` that contains your data set.

[image]

Comment: I already know about this conditional formatting but I am looking for the VBA code here. Thanks for helping

Comment: @DeepakL why reinvent the wheel? Especially when you are unable to

Comment: Actually I have a big macro I want to include this check to that so the macro will be perfect

Comment: @DeepakL Macros can integrate with Excel core functionality. You can test for the output of a Conditional Format using `DisplayConditions`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        arr = .Range("J2" & ":L" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 3) Then

                .Range("J" & i + 1 & ":L" & i + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not want the K column to be highlighted, so what needs to be done here

Comment: Also this macro is checking from the J2 row but for me this should check from J11 row only

Comment: @DeepakL If you've already got a macro working, you should be able to adapt this for your needs quite easily